# Run wc and display only the word count

Tags: shell, wc

I have been trying to create a file called `~/dictwords.txt`, which contains the number of words found in the file `/usr/share/dict/words`.

I already created the file then I removed it because I did it wrong I originally did the echo command. Then I tried this command and was so excited because I thought I was correct.

```
wc -w /usr/share/dict/words > ~/dictwords.txt
```

It's still wrong, I am supposed to have just the number, without a file name.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By default, `wc` print result along with filenames. If you want only the result, you must make `wc` read input from stdin:

```
</usr/share/dict/words wc -w > ~/dicwords.txt
```

With your current solution, you can use some other tools to get only the result from `wc`, like `cut`, `awk`, `grep`...

```
wc -w /usr/share/dict/words | cut -d' ' -f1 > ~/dicwords.txt
```

Though that assumes an implementation of `wc` that doesn't add space characters before the number, which is not the case of every `wc` implementation.

Answer (score 1):

If you will need to use the words count in the script, you can save the value into a variable:

```
numWords=$(wc -w /usr/share/dict/words | tr -dc '0-9')
```

else, you can save it into the file:

```
wc -w /usr/share/dict/words | tr -dc '0-9' > ~/dicwords.txt
```

Comment: This would potentially produce unexpected results if the pathname of the input contained digits. In the case of `/usr/share/dict/words` it's obviously fine.

Answer (score 1):

The file `/usr/share/dict/words` ought to contain one word per line. On some systems I imagine that it could possibly contain one "dictionary term" per line and that each of these may be made up from more than one space-delimited word, but I have never seen this myself.

You get the number of lines with one of

- `wc -l </usr/share/dict/words` (counts the number of newlines in the file)
- `sed -n '$=' /usr/share/dict/words` (at the last line, output the current line number)
- `awk 'END { print NR }' /usr/share/dict/words` (at the end of input, output the number of records (lines) read)
- `grep -c '[^[:space:]]' /usr/share/dict/words` (count the number of lines that have at least one non-space(-like) character)

Of these, the `wc -l` variation is least portable as it may output, or not output, extra spaces before and/or after the actual number.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk 'BEGIN{sum=0}{sum=sum+NF}END{print sum}' /usr/share/dict/words >~/dictwords.txt
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is a solution using `cat`, which avoids printing the filename after the result.

```
cat /usr/share/dict/words | wc -w
```

Comment: @StephenKitt: What additional explanation do you want? It seems pretty thorough and useful to me.

Comment: @Flimzy it’s effectively the same as `</usr/share/dict/words wc -w` in the accepted answer, so as-is it’s not useful.

Comment: No, it's quite different. As explained (in not so many words), by reading stdin, wc omits the filename in the output.

Comment: It also reads the file into a pipe and feeds it back out out into `wc`, which is minor but still worse than using `cut` and friends on `wc`'s result. You can save a few keystrokes, I guess.

Comment: @Flimzy Using a redirection into `wc`, as Stephen showed in his comment, makes `wc` read the file from standard input.